# import module from s3 in sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, python-module

I have a .py file in an s3 bucket which I am trying to load in as a python module within Sagemaker

I've tried adding the file path to the sys path with:

```
sys.path.append('foo')
```

but get an error with :

```
import bar.py
```

I can read the py file  with:

```
pd.read_csv('foo/bar.py')
```

but get an error with:

```
open('foo/bar.py)
```

Please can you guide me in how to import this .py file as a module

Answer (score 0):

You can first download the from S3:

```
import os
os.system("aws s3 cp s3://<S3location> .")
```

Then you can import the file.